# WebView2 ExecuteScriptAsync method returns encoded HTML

Tags: c#, html, webview2

I am using Microsoft Webview2 to load a web page and below code is used to read the HTML content

```
string html = await webView1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

The resulting output html appears with all tag opening, closing and other special characters encoded like below

```
\u003Chtml lang=\"en\" data-mode=\"light\">\u003Chead>\n    \u003Cmeta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    \u003Cmeta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\u003Ctitle data-argonaut-actions=\"true
```

Why does this happen? How do I get plain HTML?

Comment: Manual says that function returns "A JSON encoded string that represents the result of running the provided JavaScript." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1722.45)

Comment: Yes, the result of ExecuteScriptAsync in this case is a string containing a JSON encoded string. So you need to parse the result as JSON and get the string value out of it. This is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/javascript#scenario-executescript-json-encoded-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = await webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
html = Regex.Unescape(html);
html = html.Remove(0, 1);
html = html.Remove(html.Length - 1, 1);
```